# Kinect gives a "NotReady" status in .Net samples works in C++ samples

Tags: kinect

I'm trying to use the Kinect SDK v1 with an Xbox Kinect sensor. I installed the SDK on my dev machine and I launched the samples. The C# samples do not work, I either get "oops there was an error" or a "NotReady" status and FPS is stuck at -1.

At first I thought this was a problem with the device itself, so I tried installing the SDK on my laptop and the samples work on that fine, both the C# and C++. So the kinect device itself is ok.

I've reinstalled the SDK on my development machine, and I still have the same issues.

Any ideas/solutions?

EDIT: I should note that I have previoulsy developed with this kinect under the 1.0 SDK and when I debug my own app the sensor status enum is still "NotReady"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is dev machine configuration different from laptop. In the release notes @ http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/release-notes.aspx it's mentioned that

USB host controller compatibility
The Kinect for Windows drivers have encountered compatibility problems with certain USB host controllers when tested in specific computer configurations. Some examples of these controllers are the AMD Fusion A75 USB2.0 controller, the Etron USB 3.0 Extensible Host Controller, or the Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Controller. On those controllers, you may encounter a problem, such as a low RGB frame rate, or a Not Ready status when plugging/unplugging a Kinect. These compatibility problems are more likely to occur on PC's running the Windows 8 Developer Preview, or if you plug/unplug multiple devices repeatedly. If this happens to you, you may have to restart your app or reboot your computer. You can also try plugging your device into another USB 2.0 controller.

Comment: I can't see anything that would make the device fail. It is connected to a USB 2.0 port which is apparently all it requires.

Comment: If the driver is installed correctly:
Look for the solid green LED on the Microsoft Kinect for Windows sensor.
The Microsoft Kinect for Windows sensor will appear in Device Manager as the following nodes under "Microsoft Kinect":
Microsoft Kinect Audio Array Control, 
Microsoft Kinect Camera, 
Microsoft Kinect Security Control.
The Microsoft Kinect for Windows sensor's microphone array will appear under Sound, video and game controllers in Device Manager as:
Microsoft Kinect USB Audio.

Comment: It's a Xbox Kinect Sensor. I see all of the correctly installed devices in device manager. It runs under the C++ sample, just not under the C# sample. Hence my confusion.