# No ready kinect found?

Tags: kinect

I am beginner to Kinect pogramming. I have already installed the windows sdk. I tried to run the samples in the developer tookit. However, it said that "no ready kinect found". I know know why. Could anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Yuanhui

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the computer after installing the SDK? The [read me](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/readme.htm) states that some USB controllers require a reboot .

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982005
Have you tried the C++ samples?

Comment: I re-install the SDK according to the read me. Problem solved. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can someone provide this as an answer so it can be marked as 'Solved' please?

Answer (score 4):

I am also a beginner. Actually I just got the kinect yesterday and encountered the same problem as you. The sdk I installed is v1.8. Here is how I checked everything and solved it:

1. Look into the device manager to check if the drivers are all setup;
2. Check if you have the latest DirectX installed, Here's [the way](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179113);
3. Check if the .Net 4.0 or above has been installed;
4. Make sure that your installation is clean, which means that the kinect should be unplugged during the installation. And make sure that you restart your computer after you have the sdk and developer toolkit installed.